# How to access spiders attributes after crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I've created a test spider. This spider gets one object which has `url` and `xpath` attributes. It scrapes the `url` and then populates `self.result` dictionary accordingly. So `self.result` can be `{'success':True,'httpresponse':200}` or `{'success':False,'httpresponse':404}` etc.

The problem is that I don't know how to access `spider.result` since there is no object spider.

```
..
    def test(self):
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
        ts = TestSpider

        process = CrawlerProcess({...})

        process.crawl(ts,[object,])
        process.start()
        print ts.result
```

I tried:

```
   def test(self):
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
        ts = TestSpider(object)      
        process = CrawlerProcess({...})

        process.crawl(ts)
        process.start()
        print ts.result
```

But it says that crawl needs 2 arguments.

Do you know how to do that? I don't want to save results into the file or db.

Comment: `CrawlerProcess.crawl` requires spider class argument and you are passing a spider object. Could explain a use case for this? This seems unnecessary complicated

Comment: You can try `process.crawlers[0].spider.result` but there's probably more elegant solution

Comment: You can use logging.INFO

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you call `crawl`

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(TestSpider() , arg1=val1, arg2=val2)
```